# How to match beginning of string or character in Python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string consisting of parameter number _ parameter number:

```
dir = 'a1.8000_b1.0000_cc1.3000_al0.209_be0.209_c1.344_e0.999'
```

I need to get the number behind a parameter chosen, i.e.

- `par='be'` -->need 0.209
- `par='e'` -->need 0.999

I tried:

```
num1 = float(re.findall(par + '(\d+\.\d*)', dir)[0])
```

but for `par='e'` this will match `0.209` *and* `0.999`, so I tried to match the parameter together with the beginning of the string or an underscore:

```
num1 = float(re.findall('[^_]'+par+'(\d+\.\d*)', dir)[0])
```

which didn't work for some reason.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your `[^_]` pattern matches *any character that is not the underscore*.

Use a `(..|..)` *or* grouping instead:

```
float(re.findall('(?:^|_)' + par + r'(\d+\.\d*)', dir)[0])
```

I used a `(?:..)` non-capturing group there so that it doesn't interfere with your original group indices.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> dir = 'a1.8000_b1.0000_cc1.3000_al0.209_be0.209_c1.344_e0.999'
>>> par = 'e'
>>> re.findall('(?:^|_)' + par + r'(\d+\.\d*)', dir)
['0.999']
>>> par = 'a'
>>> re.findall('(?:^|_)' + par + r'(\d+\.\d*)', dir)
['1.8000']
```

To elaborate, when using a character group (`[..]`) and you *start* that group with the caret (`^`) you invert the character group, turning it from matching the listed characters to matching *everything else* instead:

```
>>> re.findall('[a]', 'abcd')
['a']
>>> re.findall('[^a]', 'abcd')
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! But could you explain what the ?: actually does?

Comment: @user1638145: it let's us group things like normal parenthesis, but the contents will not be put into a capturing group. The number matching group (`(\d.\d*)`) on the other hand, *does* capture and thus is returned as the first value; you have selected it by using the `[0]` index. If I had not used the `?:` indicator you'd have 2 values returned for every match: `['_', '0.999']` for `'e'`, or `['', '1.8000']` for `'a'`, for example.

Comment: I think you need an "r" in front of part of the regex... ``r'(\d+\.\d*)``.

Comment: Great! We can point to a beginning of string *or* another character sequence explicitly with help of non-capturing parentheses.

Comment: Is there no way at all to include the start of string anchor (^) inside a square bracket group without it negating the group (e.g. `[^_]` as in OP) or being a literal caret (e.g. `[\^]` with an escape)?

Comment: @HarveyAdcock: no. `^` is an anchor, and character classes only take characters, not anchors. Use `|` alternatives in a (non-capturing) group: `(?:^|_)` or `(?:^|[_<>.?])` if your character class is more than just one character.

Answer (score 0):

without `regex` solution:

```
def func(par,strs):
    ind=strs.index('_'+par)+1+len(par)
    ind1=strs.find('_',ind) if strs.find('_',ind)!=-1 else len(strs)
    return strs[ind:ind1]
```

**output:**

```
>>> func('be',dir)
'0.209'
>>> func('e',dir)
'0.999'
>>> func('cc',dir)
'1.3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regex:

```
>>> def get_value(dir, parm):
...     return map(float, [t[len(parm):] for t in dir.split('_') if t.startswith(parm)])
... 
>>> get_value('a1.8000_b1.0000_cc1.3000_al0.209_be0.209_c1.344_e0.999', "be")
[0.20899999999999999]
```

If there are multiple occurrences of the parameter in the string, all of them are evaluated.

And a version without casting to a float:

```
return [t[len(parm):] for t in dir.split('_') if t.startswith(parm)]
```

Comment: I would replace float with int. Float adds the numbers on the end which is not the exact result he was after. Otherwise this is an extremely pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: `int` is not a good idea, as information would be lost due to rounding. Still, we could skip the conversion to a number (I'll edit the answer in a second).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?P<param>[a-zA-Z]*)(?P<version>[^_]*)
```